# How to select a existing columns and run a statistical test with a function?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df). To create a new dataframe (df1), I want to select columns from the original dataframe (df). With df1, I want to omit NAs and run a statistical test. Finally, I want this process as a function.

```
library(dplyr)

#create example dataframe
A<-c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1)
B<-c(5,2,4,1,5,1,NA)
D<-c(99,99,88,88,99,99,88)
E<-c(10,10,20,10,20,20,20)
df <- data.frame(A,B,D,E)

#Single step process works
df1 <- dplyr::select(df, A, B)
df1 <- na.omit(df1)

wilcox.test(df1$B~df1$A)

#Function does not work
lazy <- function(x,y,z){
  x <- dplyr::select(df, y, z)
  x <- na.omit(x)

  e <- wilcox.test(x$z~x$y)
  return(e)
}
lazy(df2,A,E)
```

ERROR:  Error in inds_combine(.vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n

Comment: i think you're going to need to use one of those highly-intuitive [dplyr programming paradigms](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), `quo` or `!!` or `{{` depending on the version you have installed. I have 0.8.3, and I have to use the `{{` one: `x <- dplyr::select(df, {{y}}, {{z}})` and `e <- wilcox.test({{z}} ~ {{y}}, x)` get your function to work for me

Comment: @rawr so make it an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lazy <- function(x, y, z){
    x <- df[c(y, z)]
    x <- na.omit(x)

    e <- wilcox.test(x[[z]]~x[[y]])
    return(e)
}
lazy(df, "A", "B")
```