# R: paired t-test on multiple columns

Tags: r

I am trying to run a t-test on multiple columns. Basically trying to find the change from baseline to year 1 for a number of joint angles. I only want to conduct this on the study side. Below is an image with the first few rows and columns of the data. [Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0MDv.png)

I have tried using both of these functions without success:

Code 1:

```
res <- FAI_SLS %>% 
  filter(study_side == "Study")%>%
  select(-id,-subject,-activity,-side,-study_side,-year) %>%
  map_df(~ broom::tidy(t.test(. ~ year)), .id = 'var')
```

I get the following error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'year' not found

I tried taking out -year but I still have the same issue.

Code 2:

```
t(sapply(FAI_SLS%>%filter(study_side == "Study")%>%select(-id,-subject,-activity,-side,-study_side,-year), function(x) 
     unlist(t.test(x~FAI_SLS$year)[c("estimate","p.value","statistic","conf.int")])))
```

I get the following error:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': variable lengths differ (found for 'FAI_SLS$year')

Again I tried taking -year out without success.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278382/how-to-select-a-existing-columns-and-run-a-statistical-test-with-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Try fitting the t-test within `summarise()` on all the columns you want to test (selected in `across()`). Here's an example with a different dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data("storms")

storms %>% 
  filter(year %in% c(2019, 2020)) %>% 
  summarise(across(-c(name, year, status, category), 
                ~broom::tidy(t.test(. ~ year)))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "variable") %>% 
  unnest(value)

#> # A tibble: 9 × 11
#>   variable    estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic  p.value parameter conf.low
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 month         0.0917      8.93      8.84     1.15  2.52e- 1      892.  -0.0654
#> 2 day           4.29       18.2      13.9      7.49  2.34e-13      641.   3.17  
#> 3 hour         -0.0596      9.13      9.19    -0.128 8.99e- 1      687.  -0.978 
#> 4 lat           2.14       25.9      23.7      3.75  1.94e- 4      668.   1.02  
#> 5 long          6.06      -60.7     -66.8      4.27  2.25e- 5      736.   3.27  
#> 6 wind          8.42       58.8      50.4      4.42  1.18e- 5      529.   4.68  
#> 7 pressure     -4.46      989.      993.      -3.03  2.59e- 3      537.  -7.35  
#> 8 tropicalst…   7.39      153.      145.       0.810 4.18e- 1      701. -10.5   
#> 9 hurricane_…  10.9        24.1      13.2      3.92  1.02e- 4      508.   5.45  
#> # … with 3 more variables: conf.high <dbl>, method <chr>, alternative <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Not R, but interpreting multiple p-values can be fraught w/ errors. In propaganda/marketing tactics, for example, it's one of the fundamental bases of "cherrypicking".

Comment: I don't disagree, I am not sure if there is a better way? Beside hypothesis testing and only looking as specific variables of interest?

Comment: @lhs I tried using the code that you suggested without success. `res <- FAI_SLS %>% 
  filter(study_side == "Study")%>%
        filter(year != 2)%>%
  summarise(across(-c(id, year, subject, activity, side, study_side,year), 
                ~broom::tidy(t.test(. ~ year)))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "variable") %>% 
  unnest(value)`

Comment: I got the following error :  Error in `across()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% unnest(value)
  4. plyr::summarise(...)
  5. [ base::eval(...) ] with 1 more call
  7. dplyr::across(...)
  8. dplyr:::across_setup(...)
  9. dplyr:::peek_mask("across")
 10. dplyr:::context_peek("mask", fun)

Comment: The `summarise()` I'm using is from the `dplyr` package so if you don't load the libraries as I have in the code, you may have package conflicts. If you have to load `plyr` load if before `dplyr` or use `dplyr::summarise()`